# Does 䁤=香季切 and 侐=火季切 being separate 小韻s in 廣韻 imply anything?

Tags: phonology, middle-chinese

[Link](https://ytenx.org/kyonh/sieux?cjeng=%E6%9B%89&yonh=%E8%84%82A&deuh=3&tongx=&ho=)

Is it something related to 重紐? If not, how can I interpret this?

Comment: In 广韵校释, 蔡梦麒 writes:

> 本紐與䁤香季切同音，當併入 *This 韵 has the same pronunciation with 䁤 and should be merged to 䁤.*

Comment: Such phenomenon is commonly seen when a new character was added when 广韵 was compiled. See https://byvoid.com/zhs/blog/kuangx-yonh-dryung-nriux/. In this case, 侐 is also listed in 王三(=刊谬补缺切韵), nonetheless is at the end of 至韵. Maybe it is also a newly-added character 增加字 in some earlier version of 切韵. See 龙宇纯's 唐写全本王仁昫刊谬补缺切韵校笺.